# logs aggregation in grafana

Tags: logging, grafana, grafana-loki

I have a log file containing logs that looks like this:

```
{"log_time": "2020-05-28 16:09:02", "log_level": "INFO", "event": "register", "login_key": "key1", "email": "user1.email.com", some other fields}   
{"log_time": "2020-05-28 16:09:03", "log_level": "INFO", "event": "register", "login_key": "key2", "email": "user2.email.com" some other fields}
{"log_time": "2020-05-28 16:09:05", "log_level": "INFO", "event": "button click", "login_key": "key1", some other fields}
{"log_time": "2020-05-28 16:09:06", "log_level": "INFO", "event": "page view", "login_key": "key2", some other fields}
```

every user is getting a login key that is logged with all of his/her actions.
also the first event is the register event that contains the user email.

maybe I am jumping here over my head but I am trying to create a table in Grafana that will show for each login key it's email and last event.
so for this case it would be:

```
login_key   email             event           time
key1        user1@email.com   button click  2020-05-28 16:09:05
key2        user2@email.com   page view     2020-05-28 16:09:06
```

I tried to make a table using Loki as data source with the relevant derived fields but couldn't make the aggregation or even make the table show the fields I wanted.

any ides on how to do it using loki or even another data source?
I was think of trying it with elasticsearch by my log file is not that big and setting up all the filebeat-logstash-elasticsearch for it seems a bit of overhead. 
I was even thinking to write a python script to generate the table and save it to my postgres which is already connected to the grafana but feels wrong.

any help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

OK so, one important fact that you should keep in mind is that **Loki** differs a lot from other logs aggregation systems such as **ELK** or **Splunk**. While those extract and index by themselves and they respective forwarders merely send lines, **Loki**

> does not do full text indexing on logs [source](https://github.com/grafana/loki)

Most of the tagging is realized by the log forwarder (e.g. [promtail](https://github.com/grafana/loki/tree/master/docs/clients/promtail) but other forwarders can be used)

To extract data from your logs, you'll need to had a [pipeline](https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/master/docs/clients/promtail/pipelines.md) to promtail's `scrape_configs`. Here is an example:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
- job_name: system
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: varlogs
      __path__: /var/log/*log
- job_name: nginx
  static_configs:
  - targets:
      - localhost
    labels:
      job: nginxlogs
      __path__: /var/log/nginx/*log

  pipeline_stages:
  - match:
      selector: '{job="nginxlogs"}'
      stages:
      - regex:
          expression: '.*level\s?=\s?(?P<level>[A-Z]*).*ip\s?=\s?(?P<ip>[0-9\.]*).*domain\s?=\s?(?P<domain>[a-z0-9\.]*).*http_status\s?=\s?(?P<http_status>[0-9]*).*user_agent\s?=\s?(?P<user_agent>.*)-'
      - labels:
          level:
          ip:
          domain:
          http_status:
          user_agent:
```

Here, while collecting `nginxlogs`, **promtail** will look for some patterns of string based on the regex expression to send those to Loki. While exploring Loki with Grafana > 6.6, you'll then see these labels

### About your specific case

#### How to get labels

It looks like your logs have already been structured in a **json format**. From this, it does not follow that **Loki** will treat these as fields. You would need to explicitly indicate in your pipeline that:

- your logs are structured in JSON
- the fields you want to send to **Loki**

```yaml
scrape_configs:
...
  pipeline_stages:
    - match:
      selector: '{name="name_of_your_job"}'
      stages:
      # The JSON stage reads the log line as a JSON string and extracts
      # the "level" field from the object for use in further stages.
      - json:
          expressions:
            log_time: log_time
            event: event
            login_key: login_key
            etc: etc
```

#### How to aggregate by label while using LogQL?

Have a look at [this](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/#aggregation-operators). The general syntax is:

```sh
<aggr-op>([parameter,] <vector expression>) [without|by (<label list>)]
```

However, this is to transform logs into **metrics** (say, *the rate of keys used*).

```
avg(rate(({job="name_of_your_job"})[10s])) by (login_key)
```

In your case, you are not looking for an **aggregation**. More for some way to display last lines

Comment: thanks for the detail response, but I was looking for a way to make aggregations on the results, specifically grouping by the login key and foreach group show the last log (by log time) and event.